# setPasswordAttribute on User model screws with built-in auth, how to correct?

Tags: php, laravel

I created CRUD for managing users in my app. Now, my issue is that I am using `User::create(request()->all())`, and I had implemented a `setPasswordAttribute` method within my model which automatically bcrypted the password, and it worked well...however...

I just discovered that this screws with some of Laravels built-in traits which the auth uses such as `ResetsPasswords`. So me implementing that `setPasswordAttribute` method actually caused the auth scaffolding to start double-bcrypting the password, causing it to fail when the user tried logging in after resetting their password.

For the sake of clean code, I'm wondering the best way I can correct this. I know I can just use `save` instead of `create`, but I'd like to keep my controllers small and tidy as possible.

What is the best way to handle this? I was thinking of simply bcrypting the value of the actual request input, but that seems hacky.

Comment: Issue still exists in Laravel 7.x for folks that stumble upon this years later...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use another name for this field in your html form, for example `plain_password`, and then use a mutator with this name that mutates the `password` field.
This way, you don't have to write extra code and the Laravel code itself wont use this mutator.

```
public function setPlainPassword($value) {
     $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($value);
}
```